# Difference between MultiOutputRegressor(RandomForestRegressor()) versus RandomForestRegressor() when predicting multiple outputs?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

It's not clear to me why some resources online demonstrate a multi-target Random Forest regression as being instantiated as either

```
model = MultiOutputRegressor(RandomForestRegressor())
```

versus:

```
model = RandomForestRegressor()
```

when both seemingly generate multiple regressed outputs. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The internal models are different, but they are both multioutput regressors.

`MultiOutputRegressor` fits one random forest for each target.  Each tree inside then is predicting one of your outputs.

Without the wrapper, `RandomForestRegressor` fits trees targeting all the outputs at once.  The split criteria are based on the average impurity reduction across the outputs.  See the [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-multioutput).

The latter may be better computationally, since fewer trees are being built.  It can also make use of the fact that the several outputs for a given input may well be correlated.  That's all discussed in the user guide as well.

Some conjecture on my part: On the other hand, if the several outputs for a given input are *not* correlated, internal splits that are good for one output may be lousy for other inputs, so simply averaging them might not work as well.  I think in that case increasing the tree complexity can alleviate the issue (but will also take more computation).